# How can I save function call in android and use it latter again Android

Tags: android, kotlin

Lets say I have a function `fun myFunction(name:String, email:String){}` and when I call this function `myFunction('Ali', 'ali@test.com')` how can I save this call and use it later same exactly call with same parameters?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you're trying to accomplish? It's not clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrap the function call itself into a new function and save it by assigning it to a variable:

```
val savedFun = { myFunction("Ali", "ali@test.com") }
```

Then call it whenever you need it: `savedFun()`

Comment: Perfect Solution! Exactly what I was looking for, Thanks

Comment: Can you please guide me how I can save multiple function calls in a list and then call them one by one?

Answer (score 2):

Since the question came up in the comments:

> How I can save multiple function calls in a list and then call them one by one?

If you don't want to pass in any parameters to your lambdas and don't care for the return value you can do something like this:

```
val functionList = listOf(
    { myFunction("Ali", "ali@test.com") },
    { myFunction("John", "john@doe.com") },
    { println("hello") }
)

functionList.forEach{ it() } // invoke them one by one
```

In case you are interested, the inferred type of functionList is `List<() -> Unit>`